# Convert String to Money Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

I am having a problem converting input String to money. I am creating a spring boot application with thymeleaf. I have a web page where user inputs the data and there is a particular field where he inputs the String and it needs to be converted to type joda.money as in my pojo class that field has money data type. This is a full governor_form.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>[[${pageTitleG}]]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center"><h2>[[${pageTitleG}]]</h2></div>
    <form th:action="@{/governors/save}" method="post" th:object="${governor}" style="max-width: 550px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{idGovernor}">
        <div class="border border-secondary rounded p-3">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Full name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{fullName}" class="form-control" required minlength="5" maxlength="70">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Age</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" th:field="*{age}" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Position</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" step="0.01" th:field="*{position}" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Date of Intercession</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="date" th:field="*{dateOfIntercession}" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Date of Resignation</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="date" th:field="*{dateOfResignation}" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Per Capita Income</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" th:field="*{perCapitaIncome}" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Population Below Poverty</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" th:field="*{populationBelowPoverty}" class="form-control" required min="0" max="99">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select th:field="*{state}" class="form-control" required>
                        <th:block th:each="state : ${listStates}">
                            <option th:text="${state.officialStateName}" th:value="${state.idState}"/>
                        </th:block>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-2" onclick="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cancelForm() {
        window.location = "[[@{/governors}]]";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is where he inputs that data:

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Per Capita Income</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="number" step="0.01" th:field="*{perCapitaIncome}" class="form-control" required>
     </div>
</div>
```

So if i'm not mistaken Hibernate is having a problem converting a String input from thymeleaf to type money as I get the following error:

```
: Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'governor' on field 'perCapitaIncome': rejected value [1100]; codes [typeMismatch.governor.perCapitaIncome,typeMismatch.perCapitaIncome,typeMismatch.org.joda.money.Money,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [governor.perCapitaIncome,perCapitaIncome]; arguments []; default message [perCapitaIncome]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.money.Money' for property 'perCapitaIncome'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.money.Money' for property 'perCapitaIncome': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

This is the `joda.money` dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
     <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is a POJO class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "governor")
public class Governor implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_governor")
private Integer idGovernor;

@Column(name = "pib")
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "age")
private Integer age;

@Column(name = "position")
private String position;

@Column(name = "date_of_intercession")
private java.sql.Date dateOfIntercession;

@Column(name = "date_of_resignation")
private java.sql.Date dateOfResignation;

@Column(name = "per_capita_income")
private Money perCapitaIncome;

@Column(name = "population_below_poverty")
private Integer populationBelowPoverty;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_state", nullable = false)
private State state;

public State getState() {return state;}

public void setState(State state) {this.state = state;}

public Integer getIdGovernor() {
    return this.idGovernor;
}

public void setIdGovernor(Integer idGovernor) {
    this.idGovernor = idGovernor;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return this.fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {this.fullName = fullName;}

public Integer getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getPosition() {
    return this.position;
}

public void setPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public java.sql.Date getDateOfIntercession() {
    return this.dateOfIntercession;
}

public void setDateOfIntercession(java.sql.Date dateOfIntercession) {
    this.dateOfIntercession = dateOfIntercession;
}

public java.sql.Date getDateOfResignation() {
    return this.dateOfResignation;
}

public void setDateOfResignation(java.sql.Date dateOfResignation) {
    this.dateOfResignation = dateOfResignation;
}

public Money getPerCapitaIncome() {
    return this.perCapitaIncome;
}

public void setPerCapitaIncome(Money perCapitaIncome) {
    this.perCapitaIncome = perCapitaIncome;
}

public Integer getPopulationBelowPoverty() {
    return this.populationBelowPoverty;
}

public void setPopulationBelowPoverty(Integer populationBelowPoverty) {
    this.populationBelowPoverty = populationBelowPoverty;
}
}
```

This is a controller:

```
@Controller
public class GovernorController {
@Autowired
GovernorService governorService;

@Autowired
GovernorRepository governorRepository;

@Autowired
StateRepository stateRepository;
@Autowired
StateService stateService;

@GetMapping("/governors")
public String showAllGovernors(Model model){
    List<Governor> listGovernors = governorService.findAllGovernors();
    model.addAttribute("listGovernors", listGovernors);
    return "governors";
}

@GetMapping("/governors/new")
public String showNewGovernorForm(Model model){
    List <State>  listStates = stateService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("listStates", listStates);
    model.addAttribute("governor", new Governor());
    model.addAttribute("pageTitleG", "Add New Governor");
    return "governor_form";
}

@PostMapping("/governors/save")
public String saveGovernor (Governor requestGovernor, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    governorRepository.save(requestGovernor);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageG", "The governor has been saved successfully!");
    return "redirect:/governors";
}

@GetMapping("/governors/edit/{id}")
public String showEditGovernorForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    try {
        Governor governor = governorService.findGovernorById(id);
        List <State>  listStates = stateService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("listStates", listStates);
        model.addAttribute("governor", governor);
        model.addAttribute("pageTitleG", "Edit Governor (ID: " + id + ")");
        return "governor_form";
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageG", e.getMessage());
        return "redirect:/governors";
    }
}

@GetMapping("/governors/delete/{id}")
public String deleteGovernor(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    try {
        governorService.deleteGovernor(id);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageG", "The governor ID " + id + " has been deleted!");
    } catch (StateNotFoundException e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageG", e.getMessage());
    }
    return "redirect:/governors";
}
```

}

How do I convert String to Money?

Comment: How is it related to HTML?

Comment: Missinput sorry

Comment: @ArchitGargi Absolutely it is related to html because `div, label, input` etc this is part of html not thymeleaf.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej It is but that is not how tag system work. Since the problem is in anyway not related to HTML it shouldn’t contain the tags. If I am building a website which uses css too and I have a problem of JavaScript in it, I won’t add CSS too in the tags unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Iva_Only_Java Where is your controller code

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I added it have a look

Comment: How the value of perCapitaIncome field value looks like when you send it to controller? How Governor class looks like?

Comment: @Nemanja I added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create custom deserilizer for Money field, and then use Jackson to set it.

Here is code snippet:

**MoneyDeserializer.java :**

```
public class MoneyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<BigMoney> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2518470236548239933L;


    public MoneyDeserializer() {
        super(Money.class);
    }

    @Override
    public BigMoney deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return BigMoney.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, jp.readValueAs(Double.class));
    }
}
```

**Governor.java**

```
import com.example.demo.filter.MoneyDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import org.joda.money.BigMoney;
import org.joda.money.Money;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Governor implements Serializable {

    private Integer idGovernor;


    private String fullName;


    private Integer age;


    private String position;


    private java.sql.Date dateOfIntercession;


    private java.sql.Date dateOfResignation;



    private BigMoney perCapitaIncome;


    private Integer populationBelowPoverty;




    public Integer getIdGovernor() {
        return this.idGovernor;
    }

    public void setIdGovernor(Integer idGovernor) {
        this.idGovernor = idGovernor;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return this.fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {this.fullName = fullName;}

    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getDateOfIntercession() {
        return this.dateOfIntercession;
    }

    public void setDateOfIntercession(java.sql.Date dateOfIntercession) {
        this.dateOfIntercession = dateOfIntercession;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getDateOfResignation() {
        return this.dateOfResignation;
    }

    public void setDateOfResignation(java.sql.Date dateOfResignation) {
        this.dateOfResignation = dateOfResignation;
    }

    public BigMoney getPerCapitaIncome() {
        return this.perCapitaIncome;
    }
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MoneyDeserializer.class)
    public void setPerCapitaIncome(BigMoney perCapitaIncome) {
        this.perCapitaIncome = perCapitaIncome;
    }

    public Integer getPopulationBelowPoverty() {
        return this.populationBelowPoverty;
    }

    public void setPopulationBelowPoverty(Integer populationBelowPoverty) {
        this.populationBelowPoverty = populationBelowPoverty;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Governor{" +
                "idGovernor=" + idGovernor +
                ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", position='" + position + '\'' +
                ", dateOfIntercession=" + dateOfIntercession +
                ", dateOfResignation=" + dateOfResignation +
                ", perCapitaIncome=" + perCapitaIncome +
                ", populationBelowPoverty=" + populationBelowPoverty +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** On your form, you are passing `age` field as Double, but in your class it's declared as `Integer`. So you will get exception during deserilization process.
Same thing applys for `populationBelowPoverty` field . Also, your date format is `dd/MM/YYYY` and I think this is not supported format for jackson. It should be `YYYY-MM-dd`.

Anyway, for example, if you send a JSON like this:

```
{
     "idGovernor":1,
     "fullName":"Test",
     "age":1,
     "dateOfIntercession":"2022-06-09",
     "dateOfResignation":"2022-06-17",
     "perCapitaIncome":"123.932",
     "position":"position",
     "populationBelowPoverty":"98"
}
```

to this controller method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test/governor")
    public Governor testGovernor(@RequestBody Governor governor)  {
        return governor;

    }
```

You should get response like this :

```
{
    "idGovernor": 1,
    "fullName": "Test",
    "age": 1,
    "position": "position",
    "dateOfIntercession": "2022-06-09",
    "dateOfResignation": "2022-06-17",
    "perCapitaIncome": {
        "amount": 123.932,
        "zero": false,
        "negative": false,
        "positive": true,
        "amountMajorLong": 123,
        "negativeOrZero": false,
        "amountMinorLong": 12393,
        "amountMinor": 12393,
        "positiveOrZero": true,
        "minorPart": 93,
        "scale": 3,
        "amountMinorInt": 12393,
        "currencyUnit": {
            "code": "USD",
            "numericCode": 840,
            "decimalPlaces": 2,
            "symbol": "$",
            "numeric3Code": "840",
            "countryCodes": [
                "PR",
                "MP",
                "IO",
                "FM",
                "PW",
                "GU",
                "BQ",
                "TC",
                "VG",
                "AS",
                "VI",
                "TL",
                "UM",
                "MH",
                "EC",
                "US"
            ],
            "pseudoCurrency": false
        },
        "currencyScale": false,
        "amountMajorInt": 123,
        "amountMajor": 123
    },
    "populationBelowPoverty": 98
}
```

In your case, since you are using thymeleaf you can adjust this idea to your needs.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be an answer to the question. Thymeleaf does not use JSON.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I gave a general answer, with a focus on the logic for deserilization of the Money field which was at the essence of this question and I gave the example of json payload. I didn't mention Thymeleaf. I left it to the one who asked to adjust it to his needs.